# Accumulative Value Difference in Adjacent Intervals

Tags: discrete-signals, time-domain

im trying to implement eq. 14 of [this study](https://10.1016/j.jlp.2011.07.001), but im not sure how to set an interval in python. The equation is $sumAD[k]=sumA[k] - sumA[k+1]$, where $sumA[k]=\sum_{i=1}^{N} a[i]$. N is the total number of data points in the k-interval and k=1,2,3...(M-1), where M is the total number of the intervals in a period of test time. This is my code so far:

```
def sumA(signal):
    """ Calculate accumulated value in an interval. """
    N = len(signal)
    ssumA = np.zeros(N)
    ssumA[0] = signal[0]
    for i in range(1, N):
        ssumA[i] += ssumA[i-1] + signal[i]
    
    return ssumA
def accumulative_value_difference(signal):
    """ Calculate accumulative value difference in adjacent interval. """
    M = len(signal)
    sumAD = np.zeros(M)
    ssumA = sumA(signal)
    for k in range(1, (M - 1)):
        sumAD[k] = ssumA[k] - ssumA[k+1]
        
    return sumAD
```

Let's say i have 192000 data points and i want to sum values in an interval of 10. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that what you are doing here when you calculate
$$ssumAD[k] = ssum[k] - ssum[k+1] = \left(\sum_{i=0}^k a_i\right) - \left(\sum_{i=0} a_i\right) = -a_{k+1}$$

I can't access the link, but I am guessing that you want to compute
$$ssumAD[k] = \sum_{k D}^{(k+1)D-1} a_k$$

1. you can use [cumsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) to get the cumulative sum
2. you can use [diff](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) to get the difference.
3. You can use [slicing and striding](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#slicing-and-striding) to jump at certain intervals

Combining all of this

```py
def sum_intervals(a, D=10):
  sumA = np.cumsum(a)
  return np.diff(sumA[::D])
```

And `sum_intervals(a, 10)` or `sum_intervals(a)` will give you the sum of the points in intervals of 10.

Another approach would be to arrange the array in a matrix and adding the rows like

```py
def sum_intervals(a, D=10):
  return np.reshape(a[:(len(a) // D) * D], (-1, D)).sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Bob suggested an approach using np.cumsum and np.diff, which produced a positive result, but i analysing the data more closely and got an idea.

```
def calculate_sumAD(data, interval_length):
    sumAD = []
    for i in range(interval_length, len(data)):
        # sumA[k+1]
        current_interval_sum = sum(data[i-interval_length:i])
        # sumA[k]
        previous_interval_sum = sum(data[i-interval_length*2:i-interval_length])
        sumAD.append(previous_interval_sum - current_interval_sum)
    return sumAD
```

This code calculates the accumulative value difference as anticipated. When i compare the two results graphically i get a plot from Bob's approach as
[image]
and according to my code.
[image]

I used for both intervals a step of 5*1920, which equals 5% of the original signal.